# Передача состояния между компонентами

Tags: reactjs

По кнопке handleAddElement добавляю результат инпута в массив names, но компонент Show не видит этого результата без состояния как я понял, пытаюсь в нем отслеживать состояние массива, но безуспешно, подскажите в чем проблема.

```js
let names = [
    'name1',
    'name2',
    'name3',
];


function ElementList(props) {
    let names = props.names;
    return (
        names.map((name) =>
            <Element key={name} brand={name}/>
        ));
}

class Element extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            input: ''
        };
    }

.....

    handleAddElement = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {input} = this.state;
        this.setState({
            input: ''
        });
        names.push(input);
    }

    render () {
        const {input} = this.state;
        return (
            .....
                    <button onClick={this.handleAddElement}>Добавить</button>
            .....
        )
    }
}

class Show extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            names: names
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ElementList names={names}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас 3 компонента.

1. `Show` - главный компонент, как-то получает данные для names и передает их пропсами в ElementList.
2. `ElementList` - получает пропсами массив names на основе которого строятся компоненты `Element`
3. `Element` - конечный компонент

В итоге, `Show` должен хранить в себе состояние `names`, а также передавать ф-ю его изменения до `Element`

А что у вас происходит в `Element`? Он живет своей жизнью.

Читайте внимательно [документацию](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

```js
class Element extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        //что вообще этот стейт делает и для чего он нужен?
        this.state = {
            input: ''
        };
    }

.....

    handleAddElement = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {input} = this.state;
        this.setState({
            input: ''
        });
        names.push(input); // это что? откуда кмпонент знает про существование names?
    }

    render () {
        const {input} = this.state;
        return (
            /* const { input } = this.state; это что вобще?*/
            <button onClick={this.handleAddElement}>Добавить</button> 
        )
    }
}
```

Должно быть как-то так

```js
class Show extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            names
        };
    }

    addName(name) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ names: [...prevState.names, name] }))
    }

    render() {
        return (<div >
            //пробрасываем ф-ю изменения состояния, не забываем биндить
            <ElementList names={names} addName={this.addName.bind(this)} />
        </div>
        );
    }
}


function ElementList({ names, addName }) {
    return (
        names.map((name) =>
        // пробрасываем ф-ю до компонента - addName={addName}
            <Element key={name} brand={name} addName={addName} /> 
        ));
}


class Element extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            input: ""            
        }
    }

    handleAddElement = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addName(this.state.input)
    }

    render() {
        //Тут еще, видимо, <input /> должен быть
        return <button onClick={this.handleAddElement}> Добавить </button>
    }
}
```

Comment: //что вообще этот стейт делает и для чего он нужен? - отслеживает инпут, из рендера я его подрезал, перед тем, как сюда отправить.

names.push(input); // это что? откуда элемент знает про существование names? - т.к. массив находится вне компонента, он видим для него откуда угодно и спокойно изменялся.

В вашем примере я получаю ошибку в выражении "this.setState((prevState) => { names: [...prevState.names, name] })" - Expression statement is not assignment or call

Comment: ну да, я же ошибся, функция ничего не возвращает, скобки забыл. Должно быть this.setState((prevState) => ({ names: [...prevState.names, name] })). Вот ссылка на рабочий пример https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-shannon-lozsq?file=/src/App.js:385-454. Ответ поправил.

Comment: "т.к. массив находится вне компонента, он видим для него откуда угодно и спокойно изменялся" Вы его измените и что дальше? Как реакт узнает, что надо что-то перерисовать? Отталкивайтесь от того, что компонент видит и работает ТОЛЬКО с тем, что получает в пропсах.

Comment: Теперь в компоненте Element почему то я получаю - this.props.handleAddElement is not a function. Срисовал все с вашего примера.

"Вы его измените и что дальше? Как реакт узнает, что надо что-то перерисовать?" - это я сам понял. Я отвечал конкретно на ваш вопрос о существовании.

Comment: @MrYogurt и правильно, что вы получаете ошибку. У вас handleAddElement является методом компонента Element, он использует из пропсов ф-ую addName. В элемент button надо передавать this.handleAddElement , а не this.props.handleAddElement, т.к. в пропсах данного метода нет. В закрепленном примере именно так и написано.

Comment: У меня все так и есть, по ссылке залил все приложение, конкретно данный момент в AddOperator > handleAddOp. https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-blackwell-eu2c5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Я только сейчас понял, что забыл сохранить песочницу и вам пустую кинул, с проблемой так и не могу справиться, уже как мог бинды теребил. Вот нормальная ссылка https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-jang-jfq7g?file=/src/App.js

Comment: У вас все работает, но в компоненте Operator в 28 строке - <a href="#"><span className={brand} onClick={this.handleOpenModal}>!!!!Здесь вы не указали, что вам нужно что-то в блоке нарисовать, должно быть {brand}</span></a>. Внес 1 правку и все работает, вот ссылка с пруфом https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-microservice-5spfr?file=/src/components/Operator.js

Comment: Нет, вы искали не там ошибку, там все и так работало. Проблема с AddOperator. Для воспроизведения откройте мою песочницу, откройте последний (четвертый блок) и нажмите кнопку добавить. P.s. - вы ее уже отредактировали, сейчас новую сделаю.

Comment: Готово - https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-feynman-emuwp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113695/discussion-between-xydope-and-mryogurt).